# Problema para instalar FFMEPG con Docker

Tags: docker, azure, ffmpeg

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de Speech to text con funciones de azure con `Python` y tengo problemas con la version `FFMPEG` instalada en la imagen de `docker`.

Yo instalé en mi local la version de `FFMPEG` de la página oficial.
https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases y al hacer: `ffmpeg -version` me entrega que esta es la version instalada en mi local:

```
ffmpeg version 2023-11-27-git-0ea9e26636-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
```

Ahora en mi `dockerfile` hago

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

pensando en que me va a instalar la última versión, pero al comprobar con `ffmpeg -version` desde la función de azure desplegada me entrega:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.11-0+deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
```

y esa diferencia de versiones me esta ocasionando conflictos en el funcionamiento que busco.

Ahora intenté instalar en mi `dockerfile` la versión que tengo en mi local así:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg=2023-11-27-git-0ea9e26636-full_build-www.gyan.dev
```

Pero me genera error en el despliegue. ¿Cómo podría hacer para utilizar la misma versión que instalé en mi local?